# probability of guessing a k-digit number sequentially from n trials

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I recently encountered the following problem.
Assume that we need to guess a $k$-digit number. We guess it *digit by digit* and there are $n$ guesses in total. **What is the probability of success?**

Say, $k=5$, and $n=25$. We can spend, e.g., 9 trials guessing the first digit, then guess the second digit from the 3rd trial etc. But we cannot make more than 25 guesses in total.

I believe we should proceed as follows:

- guessed from 5 trials: $p=1/10^5$; -- we cannot make less than 5 trials when guessing step by step
- guessed from 6 trials: $p=1/10^4\cdot(1-1/10)\cdot 1/9\cdot 5$
- guessed from 7 trials: $p=1/10^3\cdot(1-1/10)^2\cdot 1/9^2\cdot \binom{5}{2}+1/10^4\cdot(1-1/10)\cdot(1-1/9)\cdot 1/8\cdot 5$, etc.

but I'm failing to generalize this scheme. And there is an additional problem that we have to set an upper bound to the number of trials at some point...

**UPDATE (09.02):** As @JMoravitz suggested, one can write an iterative scheme for computing the probability of guessing exactly $\kappa$ digits from $\eta$ trials, $f(\kappa,\eta)$. I believe that this scheme can be written as
$$f(\kappa,\eta)=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}f(\kappa−1,\eta−i),$$
where we use the fact that the probability of guessing the digit from $1\le \kappa\le 10$ guesses is always the same:
$$p(i=1)=\frac1{10},\quad p(i=2)=\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{10},...$$
We also need to add boundary conditions $$\begin{cases}f(\kappa,\eta)=0,&\eta<\kappa\mbox{ (we cannot guess $\kappa$ digits from less than $\eta$ trials)},\\
f(1,\eta)=\frac{1}{10},&0<\eta\le 10\mbox{ (probabilities of guessing the first digit from $\eta$ trials)},\\
f(1,\eta)=0,&\eta=0\mbox{ or }\eta>10.\end{cases}$$
The final probability is to be found as the sum $$p^*=\sum_{i=k}^n f(k,i)=\sum_{i=5}^{25} f(5,i).$$
This scheme looks pretty neat and can be easily computed numerically.

**However, I wonder if there is any chance to solve this problem analytically?** Perhaps there exists a different approach?...

Comment: Your numbers appear off... if I had one mistake that mistake would occur with probability $\frac{9}{10}$, not $\frac{1}{10}$.  A second mistake for the same digit given the earlier mistake would have occurred with probability $\frac{8}{9}$.  You also seem to be using $6$'s where $5$'s would have been more appropriate

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've made some first corrections and will check the expressions once again.

Comment: It seems to me like a problem that constructing a recursive function on two variables would be best suited for.  Letting $f(k,n)$ be the probability of having successfully finished guessing $k$ digits so far with exactly $n$ guesses.

Comment: Should it be something like $f(k,n)=f(k-1,n-1)*1/10+f(k-1,n-2)*9/10*1/10+...$? With boundary condition $f(1,1)=1/10$, $f(1,2)=9/10*1/10$ etc.? How should I solve it? Could you point me at an example where some similar problem is treated?

Comment: Do the digits in your guess list have to be in order?

Comment: Yes, you start by guessing the first one, then go to the second one and so on until you arrive at the last digit (if you haven't exhausted the number of trials by then).

Comment: If I already made 9 guesses for one out of ten digits, and I now _know_ the digit, do I need another guess?

Comment: @gnasher729 I was assuming that even if I had made $\ 9\ $ incorrect guesses for a given digit, I would still be required to nominate the  value of the digit which I now know to be correct, and that nomination would be counted as a "guess".  If that's not the case, then I'll need to change my answer.

Comment: I've been thinking about the problem in the way @lonza described. However, I think that it shouldn't change the problem a lot if we say that we can guess a digit from at most 9 trials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\ G_i\ $ be the number of guesses taken to determine the $\ i^\text{th}\ $ digit. Then $\ G_1,G_2,\dots\ $ are independent discrete random variables, all uniformly distributed over the integers $\ 1,2,\dots,10\ $, and the total number of guesses taken to determine every one of $\ k\ $ digits is $\ \displaystyle T_k=\sum_{i=1}^kG_i\ $.  The probability mass function $\ p_{T_k}\ $of $\ T_k\ $ is therefore the $\ k-$fold convolution of the uniform distribution over the integers $\ 1,2,\dots,10\ $:
\begin{align}
p_{T_j}(h)&=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{p_{T_{j-1}}(h-i)}{10}\\
&=\sum_{i=\max(1,h-10(j-1))}^{\min(10,h+1-j)}\frac{p_{T_{j-1}}(h-i)}{10}\ ,
\end{align}
because $\ p_{T_{j-1}}(s)=0\ $ for $\ s<j-1\ $ or $\ s> 10(j-1)\ $.

If you're allowed $\ n\ $ guesses to to get all $\ k\ $ digits correct, then your probability of success is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nT_k(i)=\sum_{i=k}^nT_k(i)\ .
$$
One convenient way of obtaining $\ p_{T_k}\ $ is to use generating functions.  The generating function $\ g_0(x)\ $ of the uniform distribution over the integers $\ 1,2,\dots,10\ $ is given by
$$
g_0(x)=\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^i\ ,
$$
and the generating function of the convolution of two probability mass functions is the product of their generating functions.  The generating function $\ g_k(x)\ $ of $\ p_{T_k}\ $ is therefore given by
$$
g_k(x)=g_0(x)^k=\frac{1}{10^k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^i\right)^k\ .
$$
The generating function of $\ p_{T_5}\ $ is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{10^5}\big(x^{50}&+5x^{49}+15x^{48}+35x^{47}+70x^{46}+126x^{45}\\
&+210x^{44}+330x^{43}+495x^{42}+715x^{41}+996x^{40}\\
&+1340x^{39}+1745x^{38}+2205x^{37}+2710x^{36}+3246x^{35}\\
&+3795x^{34}+4335x^{33}+4840x^{32}+5280x^{31}+5631x^{30}\\
&+5875x^{29}+6000x^{28}+6000x^{27}+5875x^{26}+5631x^{25}\\
&+5280x^{24}+4840x^{23}+4335x^{22}+3795x^{21}+3246x^{20}\\
&+2710x^{19}+2205x^{18}+1745x^{17}+1340x^{16}+996x^{15}\\
&+715x^{14}+495x^{13}+330x^{12}+210x^{11}+126x^{10}\\
&+70x^9+35x^8+15x^7+5x^6+x^5\big)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, the probability of determining $5$ digits with $25$ or fewer guesses is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{10^5}\big(1&+5+15+35+70+126+210+330+495+715\\
&+996+1340+1745+2205+2710+3246\\
&+3795+4335+4840+5280+5631\big)\\
&=\frac{38125}{10^5}\ .
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

May I try to offer an approach to have some estimation to this problem (and my apology in advance if what I am writing is trivial or wrong):

Let $X_i$ denote the number of guesses required to find the $i$ digit. Hence, lets denote $X = X_1+..+X_k$ as the total number of guesses. $X$ is sum of independent random variables.

It can be calculated that $\mathbb{E}X = 5.5k \; V[X] = 8.25k$

And if we denote $n = t + \mathbb{E}X$ ($t$ is not necessarily natural number, or you can take a floor of this equation) then we can have some estimation by Chevishev ineq.:
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t)\leq \frac {8.25k}{t^2}$$

Then we can get some conclusions about the problem, for instance, that for large enough numbers if the number of guesses allowed is in order of $O(k^{0.5+\epsilon})$ then we get that $$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t)\leq \frac {8.25k}{(k^{0.5+\epsilon})^2}$$
is small as we wish, and hence we get good lower bound to the probability of success:
$$1- \mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t) = \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}X - t\leq X\leq\mathbb{E}X+t = n) \leq \mathbb{P}(X\leq n)$$

Comment: I don't follow your final conclusion.  For $\ k=5\ $, $\ \mathbb{E}X=$$5.5k=$$27.5\ $, so it looks to me like $\ n=\mathbb{E}X+t\ $ should be $\ 47\ $ for $\ t=19.5\ $.  Because $\ \mathbb{E}X>25\ $ I don't see how your Chebyshev inequality can give you any *positive lower* bound for $\ \mathbb{P}(X\le25)\ $.

Comment: Because the distribution of $\ X\ $ is symmetric about its mean, your Chebyshev inequality can be used to obtain an *upper bound* on $\ \mathbb{P}(X\le25)\ $, but because $25$ is so close to the mean of $27.5$, the bound turns out to be trivial
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X\le25)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}\big(|X-\mathbb{E}X|\ge 2.5\big)}{2}\\
&\le
\frac{8.5\times5}{2\times(2.5)^2}=3.4\ .
\end{align}
The Chebyshev inequality is really only useful for estimating probabilities way out in the tail of a distribution—that is, for $\ t\ $ much larger than the standard deviation of $\ X\ $.

Comment: Hey @lonzaleggiera ! I missed it at my final remark, thats sure! but for the statement about the lower bound- it is right that
$$1- \mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t) = \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}X - t<X<\mathbb{E}X+t = n) \leq \mathbb{P}(X\leq n)$$
isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that series of relations is correct, but unless $\ n\ $  exceeds  the mean of $\ X\ $  by more than its standard deviation,  the lower bound you get from it won't be positive.

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that you have *strict* inequalities in  the probabilities on *both* sides of your equation
$$
1-\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t)=\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}X-t<X<\mathbb{E}X+t=n)\ .
$$
This would be ok if $\ X\ $ were a continuous random variable, but since it is actually *discrete* there will be certain values of $\ t\ $ for which $\ \mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|=t)>0\ $, and for those values of $\ t\ $ you will have
$$
1-\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t)>\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}X-t<X<\mathbb{E}X+t=n)\ .
$$

Comment: The correct equation for both continuous *and* discrete random variables is 
$$
1-\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}X|>t)=\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}X-t\le X\le\mathbb{E}X+t=n)\ .
$$

Comment: Yes, of course . corrected that. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: I’d change 5.5 to 5.4 because there are two digits that you can find in nine guesses. Ten guesses are never needed. And a “k digit number” cannot start with 0, so 44/9 guesses are needed on average for the first digit.